# # of Crossing of pairs continuous distribution functions and # of crossing of their inverse

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are two continuous probability distributions that cross only twice. Does that imply that $F_X^{-1}$ and $F_Y^{-1}$ also only cross twice?

Comment: If you imagine reflecting the cumulative distribution functions across the diagonal to get the inverse functions, then the answer would be yes, unless you have to deal with horizontal or vertical or superimposed *crossing*.

Comment: Thanks, your comment perfectly answers the question!